# Determine whether a linear system may have no solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say we have a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that can be written as $A=(M+\lambda I_n)^\top (M-\lambda I_n)$, where $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

I am wondering for any vector $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$, whether the following linear system

$A^\top(A^2+A)X=A^\top\xi$

may have no solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if $A=O$ and $\lambda=\pm 1$?

In this case,
\begin{align}
A&=-I_n,\\
A^2+A&=O.
\end{align}
Consequently, your equation becomes
$$
\mathbf{0}=O\mathbf{x}=-\mathbf{\xi},
$$
which does not have a solution for $\mathbf{\xi}\ne\mathbf{0}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Is it possible for $A$ to be non-zero yet have the characteristic polynomial $x^2 + x$ ?